# This： finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexMt_360Debug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

build.gradle in my project：
dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
compile project(':J2WBase')
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.17.1'
```

}

build.gradle in the third party framework:

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
```

}

I have tried to delete the build folder, re build project
Upgrade buildtools to the latest version
I think it might be a jar package duplicate reference problem, but I can't find a place to repeat, and what should I do next, since quoting'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.17.1 compile.

Comment: remove unused dependencies and clean the project and check if any library having any version  issue (old or new) resolve , it will solve the issue

Comment: Look in the gradle console. There's likely more information there. Also, make sure you've set the source and target compatibility levels (under project settings for each module) to 1.7.

Comment: Please post the full error message (example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847482/error-gradle-execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug))